# Метод `All()` для пустой коллекции возвращает `true`: баг или фича?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, инспекция-кода

У меня есть класс `Item`

```
public class Item
{
    public int ParentId {get;set;}
    public int TypeId {get;set;}
    public int? AttachedFileId {get;set;}
}
```

Мне необходимо для каждого *родителя* получить признак наличия того или иного типа. Наличием считается что отсутствуют `item` без прикрепленного файла, написал следующий запрос:

```
var items = _context.Set<Items>()
    .GroupBy(x=>x.ParentId)
    .Select(x=>new
    {
        ParentId = x.Key,
        Type1 = x.Where(x=>x.TypeId==1).Any() && x.Where(x=>x.TypeId==1).All(x=>x.AttachedFileId!=null)
        //И так для каждого типа
    })
```

Запрос возвращает данные так как мне необходимо, но мне кажется что условие
`x.Where(x=>x.TypeId==1).Any() && x.Where(x=>x.TypeId==1).All(x=>x.AttachedFileId!=null)` можно переписать

Также меня смущает, что метод `All` для пустой коллекции возвращает `true`

Пример на [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/uUSdTl)

Comment: фича очевидно :-)

Comment: а коллекция уже материализована? или это все еще и базу потом пойдет?

Comment: коллекция уже материализована, обработка будет идти на клиенте

Comment: Не вполне понял — а зачем вам Any? Ваш признак — «отсутствуют item без прикрепленного файла», а не «отсутствуют item без прикрепленного файла, но хоть какие-то item'ы есть».

Comment: @VladD если речь об этом `x.Where(x=>x.TypeId==1).Any()` то это для того чтобы проверить наличие итемов определенного типа, после ответа Squidward данное условие превратилось в `x.Any(x=>x.TypeId==1)`

Comment: @Bald: А зачем? Ваше условие же этого самого наличия не требует. Наоборот, требуется _отсутствие_.

Comment: @VladD мне надо получить булевское значение есть итем данного типа у родителя или нет. если убрать левую часть проверяющую наличие итемов определенного типа и оставить только `Where().All()` результат будет не верным: для пустой коллеции All вернет `true`, поэтому эти два условия связаны через оператор `&&`, т.е. если итемы этого типа есть то проверяется второе условие иначе итемов нет. в приведенном фидле можно в этом убедиться

Comment: @Bald: Не, у вас в вопросе написано не так. У вас не написано, что наличие родителя данного является условием. У вас лишь написано, что не должно быть родителей с таким-то условием. Вы точно уверены, что нужно ещё и наличие родителя? Моя математическая интуиция подсказывает, что вам это скорее всего не нужно.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43812/discussion-between-bald-and-vladd).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

С точки зрения математики всё верно: метод `All` — это аналог [квантора всеобщности](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80_%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8), а [для пустых множеств он всегда верен](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_quantification#The_empty_set), независимо от условия.

Этот метод реализован так (за вычетом проверок):

```
public static bool All<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
                                Func<TSource, bool> predicate) {
    foreach (TSource element in source)
        if (!predicate(element))
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

Упростить ваше выражение что-то не очень получается. Разве что нагромоздить переменные для одного прохода, но с грубым нарушением идеи функциональщины:

```
bool any = false;
bool result = x.Where(x => any = x.TypeId == 1).All(x => x.AttachedFileId != null) && any;
```

Comment: хм, а разве `Where(x.TypeId==1).All(x.AttachedFileId != null)` эквивалентно `x.All(x => x.TypeId == 1 && x.AttachedFileId != null)`? В первом случае в основной коллекции могут быть и элементы с другим TypeId, а во втором вроде не могут

Comment: См. также: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth