# почему every на пустом массиве возвращает true?

Tags: javascript

почему `[].every(el => el.selected)` возвращает `true`?

Comment: Язык не так важен, так что [дубликат](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/554196), имхо. @Athari дал очень хороший и ясный ответ по данной теме

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every

> Note: This method returns true for any condition put on an empty
>   array.
>
> Замечание: Этот метод возвращает `true` для любого условия, примененного к пустому массиву.

Answer (score 1):

Вообще, как правило эту функцию так определяют by convention. В хаскеле, например,

```
all :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool
all p = and . map p

and :: [Bool] -> Bool
and = foldr (&&) True
```

(True в последней строке — это как раз начальное значение, которое и возвращается для пустого массива.)

Собственно, это позволяет определить функцию рекуррентно. В псевдокоде было бы что-нибудь вроде:

```
every(arr, pred) = now_and_then(arr, pred, 0) where
    now_and_then(arr, pred, i) =
        i == arr.length ||
        pred(arr[i]) and now_and_then(arr, pred, i + 1)
```

При выходе за пределы массива в таком случае лучше возвращать True, иначе случай пустого массива пришлось бы разбирать отдельно.

Ну и, собственно, логическое определение: "Для любого элемента массива предикат истинен". В пустом массиве, очевидно, это истинно: отрицание высказывания — "Существует в массиве элемент, такой что значение предиката для этого элемента ложно", — но в пустом массиве нет такого элемента.